# Importing into Categories

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have an Excel CSV of products (Roughly 11000 products) and i can import them successfully but what column name does Magento require to import the products into their specific categories?

I tried the following in my excel csv but it didn't work:

```
root_category   category
Default Category    Washer
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

Even natively exported from Magento file not always suits for importing it back.

To format file in the way Magento insists, you need to include all the required fields and keep to UTF-8 encoding (without BOM).

Check this article with the list of required fields for Magento import - https://www.mag-manager.com/useful-articles/tipstricks/required-csv-file-values-for-error-free-magento-import-via-admin/